# Magit equivalent for "git remote -v" (list remotes)

Tags: magit

I'm wondering if there is a magit equivalent to `git remote -v` to list remotes and their URL's defined on a git repository.  The magit remotes popup offers options to add, remove, rename, and set url, but I don't see any sort of listing mechanism.

Sample `git remote -v` output:

```
origin  ebpa@example.com:/var/git/myproject.git (fetch)
origin  ebpa@example.com:/var/git/myproject.git (push)
```

`magit-list-remotes` is non-interactive and only lists remote names.

Comment: I do not know what the current version of magit presently has to offer, but I wrote up my own push to multiple remotes (a couple of years ago) that begins with `git remote -v` using `start-process` -- **Emacs — How to push a Git repository to multiple remotes**:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/23178396/2112489

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The buffer generated by `magit-show-refs-popup` (<kbd>y</kbd>) will
give output that includes something like

```
Origin (ebpa@example.com:/var/git/myproject.git) (2)
  origin/HEAD               -> origin/master
  origin/master             Commit message
```

It is working with the output of `git branch -vvr` rather than
`git remote -v`.