# How to view remote URLs on magit?

Tags: magit

I would like to make sure I know where I am fetching, pulling, and pushing to.
How to view remote URLs in magit?

From the magit manual "7.1.1 The Remote Popup" on https://magit.vc/manual/magit/The-Remote-Popup.html

```
M C     (magit-remote-config-popup)
        This command shows remote related variables in a separate popup.
```

The magit 'M' menu does not list 'C'.  Apparently the magit manual is not up to date.

A similar question was posted on [Magit equivalent for "git remote -v" (list remotes)](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/24879/magit-equivalent-for-git-remote-v-list-remotes)

Comment: Doesn't the answer for the question you link to show a way to see the URL?  "The magit 'M' menu does not list 'C'."  What version of Magit are you using?  The "C" seems to be there in the latest Magit: https://github.com/magit/magit/blob/0ee62ee80eca660a5d05dab34bcf4b80a3ee749d/lisp/magit-remote.el#L130

Comment: @KyleMeyer,  How to find out what version of Magit is installed?

Comment: @KyleMeyer, Emacs is telling me magit-version  Magit 20170929.2231 .  The latest version on GitHub is 2.12.0  https://github.com/magit/magit/tree/master/Documentation/RelNotes

Comment: @KyleMeyer, you're right, y r does show the remote URLs :)  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As KyleMeyer said in the comments, magit-show-refs-popup <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> shows the remote URLs:

[image]